# Google Search safety advisor

Tags: linux, security, google-search, fedora-25

I want to get a hint in Google search results page, classifying each result as a safe website or not safe.

I'm using Google Chrome on Fedora 25 operating system.

I searched a lot, but didn't succeed to find a working one.

Only found it working by using `Norton safe search` https://search.norton.com which searches in **ask.com** not **google.com**.

Any suggestion?

Comment: darroosh, How can you define "safety" for websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this extensions from avast :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/avast-online-security/gomekmidlodglbbmalcneegieacbdmki?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Which did what I want.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the chrome extension:

[WOT: Web of Trust, Website Reputation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wot-web-of-trust-website/bhmmomiinigofkjcapegjjndpbikblnp?hl=en)

> when installed, it will tell you if a website **is safe**:

[image]

> **Or not safe:**

[image]

To get this result, I used `fedora 25` and the latest `chrome 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)` browser.

Comment: Who does classify what is safe and what is not? Can we trust user-generated WOT (or any other user-gen site like SO, SU, Wikipedia)? Or can we trust anybody who just sends megabytes of unverified program code (some may call this web 2.0, 3.0 or even ECMAscript/JAVAscript and pdf and flash and html5) into user's computer to execution (in some kind of always-vulnerable sandbox, virtual machine or combination.) without any additional user knowledge and consent about this code (Do everybody plug USB-stick just found on the street and run it in some virtual machine thousands times per day?)

Comment: I did some research before posting that. WOT is a community project and it is up to date until March 21, 2017. but there is no evidence of safeness of its result. if you think this is not a good answer I'll delete that.

Comment: H. DJEMAI, This answer may help darroosh, and WOT is widely (140 million users) known project (And it is also known recently for selling user's browsing history -  ['Web Of Trust' Browser Extension Cannot Be Trusted: nov 2016, pcmag](http://www.pcmag.com/news/349328/web-of-trust-browser-extension-cannot-be-trusted); [policy](http://web.archive.org/web/20161101192113/https://www.mywot.com/en/privacy/privacy_policy) - "*IP, location, device type, OS, browser, date and time, Web addresses,..browser usage are all collected*"). But the problem with trust and safety in internet doesn't end with WOT.

Comment: my be I have to add a `warning of use` to the answer. Thank you for your comment. you seem to be a security specialist.

Comment: H. DJEMAI, the trust issues from Nob 2016 where fixed (WOT was removed from addons/extensions catalogs for some time). But using of WOT (or any other "cloud"-style addon) will send all your visited (viewed) links to the service provider (to WOT or to antivirus vendor who has similar cloud solutions) and user just **should know about it** (and read privacy policy of service). Banner removal plugins (and chrome protect) are better - they just download huge (regex) blacklists from provider (and some providers asks companies for money to exclude their ads from blacklists). (i'm not a specialist)

Comment: Thank you @H. DJEMAI , But I want a more trusted extension if available, from a known security provider like norton, mcafee, avira, kaspersky or something like that.
I found mcafee siteadvisor extension, But When I clicked the button " add to chrome" it gives error and doesn't install, So if something like it, it would be great.